# How to check if a function returned a NULL pointer AND dereference it directly, without using a throwaway intermediary pointer variable?

Tags: c

```
int * my_func(void);

int result;
if (myfunc() != NULL) {
    result = *myfunc();
}
```

I, however, can't run the function twice. And I don't want to use an intermediary pointer just for the sole purpose of checking for NULL.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the temporary variable.  As far as I can think of, C doesn't provide any other way to use the same value in more than one expression.

Comment: _Why_ don't you want to store the pointer in a variable?  That's usually the best way to communicate what it means to other programmers.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of, and it's not really even C, is GCC's [omitted second conditional operand extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Conditionals.html).  But even then you would need to provide a valid alternative pointer to dereference instead, something like `int garbage = 0; result = *(myfunc() ? : &garbage);`.  Which is awful.

Comment: The compiler may well optimize away a temporary pointer. Worry about any inefficiency if there should be an actual bottleneck.

Comment: @NateEldredge And even that loses the fact that the call failed without then checking `result` against the address of `garbage`.  So you'd wind up with more complex, harder-to-read, non-portable code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: You can't even do that, because `result` just has the value from `garbage`, not its address.  The code in the example didn't use the nullitude (?) for anything other than deciding whether to dereference and assign to `result`, but yeah, if you need more stuff in the `if` or `else` blocks, the `?:` extension won't help.

Comment: What do you want to do if `my_func` does return `NULL`? Do nothing? In that case, what do you want the value of `result` to be?

Comment: In general, it is impossible to get the return value of `my_func` by calling `myfunc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I don't want to use an intermediary pointer just for the sole purpose of checking for NULL.

Amend that goal.  Use an intermediate.

**Trust** your compiler to emit efficient code.

If you compiler does not emit efficient code, get a better compiler.

```
int * my_func(void);

int result;
int *ptr = myfunc();
if (ptr != NULL) {
    result = *ptr;
} else {
  ; // TBD code: what to do when `ptr` is NULL?
}
```

---

Perhaps it would be sufficient to wrap the `NULL` test?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int wrapper_int(int *ptr, int deefault) {
  return ptr ? *ptr : deefault;
}

int* my_func(void);

int main() {
  #define NULL_DEFAULT 42

  int result1 = wrapper_int(my_func(), NULL_DEFAULT);
  printf("%d\n", result1);

  int result2 = wrapper_int(my_func(), NULL_DEFAULT);
  printf("%d\n", result2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something horrible and allowed but not fully supported by the C standard, then do this in a dark room where nobody can see:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//  Create dummy function for demonstration.
int *myfunc(int *p) { return p; }


static void Demo(int *p)
{
    //  Create a type, not a variable.
    typedef char T0[(uintptr_t) myfunc(p)];
    if (sizeof (T0))
    {
        int *result = (int *) sizeof (T0);
        printf("myfunc returned non-null %p.\n", (void *) result);
    }
    else
        printf("myfunc returned null.\n");
}


int main(void)
{
    Demo(NULL);
    Demo((int []) {0});
}
```

Sample output:

```
myfunc returned null.
myfunc returned non-null 0x7ffee75d29fc.
```

If you are allergic to zero-length arrays, add one in the `typedef` and subtract it from the `sizeof`.